# Fatal error on Custom WebBrowser (winforms) code

Tags: c#, winforms, com, webbrowser-control

Getting a fatal exception on the CustomWebBrowser (winforms) code.

“*The  runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at  0x6c9a60c6, on thread 0xf94. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error  may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of  user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for  COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.*”

This is working fine on machines that has **.Net Framework 4.5** installed, however not in machines with ***.Net framework 4.0***

```
// constructor
    public AutoCompleteWebBrowserSite(WebBrowser host) :
        base(host)
    {

        // get the CCW object for this
        _unkOuter = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(this);
        Marshal.AddRef(_unkOuter);
        try
        {
            // aggregate the CCW object with the helper Inner object
            _inner = new AutoCompleteHelper(this);
            _unkInnerAggregated = Marshal.CreateAggregatedObject(_unkOuter, _inner);

            // obtain private WebBrowserSite COM interfaces
            try
            {
                _baseIDocHostUiHandler = (WebBrowserNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler)  Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(_unkInnerAggregated,typeof (WebBrowserNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler));
            }
            catch(Exception)
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.Release(_unkOuter);
        }
    }
```

The exception was thrown at `_baseIDocHostUiHandler = (WebBrowserNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(_unkInnerAggregated,typeof (WebBrowserNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler));`

Also tried [disabling concurrent garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec.aspx) by disabling gcConcurrent in the app.config file

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times. Rather edit your original question to add additional information or delete it before posting a new question. Your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically need to remove all the code from constructor (mainly _baseIDocHostUiHandler)

And then in the WebBrowserSite implementation, try return the default implementation value for each of the methods.

```
   private const int DefaultImpVal = unchecked((int)0x80004001)

  #region IDocHostUIHandler
            int WebBrowserNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu(int dwId, ref WebBrowserNativeMethods.Point pt, IntPtr pcmdtReserved, IntPtr pdispReserved)
            {
                return DefaultImpVal ;
            }

int WebBrowserNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowUI(int dwId, IntPtr activeObject, IntPtr commandTarget, IntPtr frame, IntPtr doc)
            {
                return DefaultImpVal;
            }
```

similarly for other methods.